# Trying to run cool-retro-term on Raspberry Pi / RetroPie / Debian Jessie

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, debian

I'm attempting to get swordfish90's excellent [cool-retro-term](https://github.com/Swordfish90/cool-retro-term) to work on the RetroPie (running Debian Jessie) for running text games with an appropriate retro flavor.

The [instructions for Debian Jessie](https://github.com/Swordfish90/cool-retro-term#build-instructions-linux) allowed me to compile, but now I don't know enough to take the next step.

To start, I installed the deps:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential qmlscene qt5-qmake qt5-default qtdeclarative5-dev qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects qml-module-qtquick-dialogs qml-module-qtquick-localstorage qml-module-qtquick-window2
```

In order to compile it without memory errors, I needed to increase my swapfile size. But then I was good to go. Though it took a while, it compiled successfully.

```
$ git clone --recursive https://github.com/Swordfish90/cool-retro-term.git
$ cd cool-retro-term
$ qmake && make
```

But when I run it, I get an error.

```
$ ./cool-retro-term
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
```

There are wide gaps in my understanding around X-windows requirements. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by trying:

```
./cool-retro-term -display :0
```

or even better:

```
bash -c "/fullpath/cool-retro-term -display :0"
```